how to use constraints and fixed position in flutter?
I am trying to show a widget in the 50x50 coordination relative to its parent with 30% width size also relative to its parent, however, Expanded can't seem to work within Positioned.
Can you please show me an example please.

What do you have on Parent widget? can you include a minimal  snippet ?

Positioned works only within Stack widget

@Md.YeasinSheikh it can be any parent widget, the point is that I need to add an absolute position to a widget relative to its parent and also its sizing relative to the parent

maybe you can try combining  LayoutBuild, CompositedTransformTarget and compositedtransformfollower widget

"the point is that I need to add an absolute position to a widget relative to its parent and also its sizing relative to the parent" use CustomSingleChildLayout then

Alternatively you could try FlowStack with the one child created with FlowStackEntry.fromCallbacks

@pskink there is no usage example regarding it

CustomSingleChildLayout is used couple of times in flutter's code, check it out (for example tooltip.dart)
